# C# not recognizing SQLConnection even when using "using System.Data.SqlClient;"

Tags: c#

Here is the code that I'm looking at -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CSharpPracticeProject
{
    class Testing
    {

        public static void main()
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = null;
            int x = 25;
            Console.WriteLine(x/4);
        }
    }

}
```

Error message - 'The type or namespace 'SqlConnection' could not be found.

It seems like other posts seem to solve the issue with the import, so Im just not sure what the issue is. This is Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Is this .NET Framework, Standard, or Core? Can you clean and rebuild?

Comment: Do you have the "Target framework" (project properties) set to `.NET Framework X Client Profile` ?

Comment: If you check your References do you have System.Data ?

Comment: By references do you mean the using keyword? This is Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, and adding using System.Data doesnt make it be recognized. Even if I enter the entire pathname when declaring the variable it isnt recognized.

Comment: @user "References" are links to other libraries. In .NET Framework projects this appears under "References" in the Solution Explorer. In .NET Core projects, it appears under "Dependencies" in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're using .NET Core, since it should work out the box with the code you have if you're using .NET Framework.

In .NET Core, you need to add a reference to `System.Data.SqlClient` via NuGet:

1. Select Tools | NuGet Package Manager | Manage NuGet Packages for Solution
2. Click "Browse"
3. Type `System.Data.SqlClient` and hit return
4. Select `System.Data.SqlClient by Microsoft`
5. On the panel on the right, check your project.
6. Click Install
7. Click OK to the next box that comes up.

Your code should now work.

---

If you're using .NET Framework, which seems unlikely given the problem you're facing, you can check if you have `System.Data` referenced by right-clicking "References" in the Solution Explorer, selecting "Assemblies" and ensuring that "System.Data" is checked.

Comment: Yes it is .NET Core, and I just did all of that and it worked. Thank you, I would have never thought of that on my own! Now I'll have to look at the differences between the two.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)